# Project Server 2010 Service Packs and Cumulative Updates

Tags: upgrade, project-server, cumulative-update, service-pack

I am taking over support of a development environment for Project Server 2010 and would like to update it to a more recent level of CU. We have one DB server, and all other components are on one additional server. I am posting this question on the sharepoint side in hopes of some guidance since so much of the Project functionality is via Sharepoint.

Current levels from the Control Panel: MS Proj Server 2010 14.0.7015.1000, MS Sharepoint Server 2010 14.0.7015.1000, Service Pack 2 KB2687452 applied. 
Farm Info: Config DB version: 14.0.6134.5001.

1. Can I apply the April CU and it will include all the previous CUs since SP2? Do I need to install the CUs one at a time?
2. For each CU, do I install the Sharepoint component first, then Project?
3. I keep reading information about problems with SP1 but I don't see it in my Control Panel as installed (just SP2.) Can I install Feb or April 2014 CU and avoid whatever issues were happening with July 2013 CU and SP1?
4. Any advice on next steps is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to check the version from the Central admin site.
regarding your questions, here are the anwsers:

1) Yes, if you apply the April CU then you will get all the cu till SP2.

2) You dont need to install the seprate component for sharepoint & project server as well, Because MSFT new Packaging method, if you apply the Project Server CU it will include all the SharePoint Server CU. So you just need Project Server CU only.

check this link for more details:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2014/04/09/april-2014-cu-for-sharepoint-2010-has-been-released.aspx

3) you will not see this issue as those things already fixed, but if you face the issue then share here again we can take a look on it.

4) Perform the full testing in your lower farm then apply to production. make sure all your DBs and server are upgraded properly after the Config wizard.